# How can I automate a script [Ruby] to run at a given time every day?

Tags: ruby, linux, scripting

I've written a webcrawler that pulls information into a report and would like to run it every day at 12:00pm.  The script is run using:

```
ruby script.rb
```

I've tried using the whenever gem (https://github.com/javan/whenever).
My directory structure is this:

```
/config
  schedule.rb
script.rb
```

In my script.rb file, I have the following:

```
every :day, :at => '12:00pm' do 
    command "ruby script.rb"
end
```

I've modified the time :at to take see if it runs and it doesn't.

I've also tried:

```
every :day, :at => '12:00pm' do 
    `ruby script.rb`
end
```

I've also looked into the "at" linux utility but it appears suited to one-time jobs.  I'd like this to generate a report everyday.

Note: the script specifies where to output so I don't need to give it an output.

---

I've also tried creating a crontab but have encountered a problem with saving.

I use http://crontab-generator.org/ to generate the correct syntax.
Then I run:

```
crontab -e
```

Which opens vi and I copy the syntax. However, it exits with a status of 1 and if I run:

```
crontab -l
```

It says there's no jobs listed.

I've also tried running this as the super user, and it exits the same.

The error message is

```
/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 1
```

I just want a command to run at a given time, what am I missing?

**Edit**
Does it matter that I'm on a Mac?

Comment: I had the problem of adding cron jobs with a Mac using Vim, too. I did `EDITOR=emacs crontab -e`, which worked for me.

Comment: @NigoroJr Thanks!  That was it! I'm not an emacs guy but sublime and vim both failed me and emacs worked.